# Compact Riemann surfaces and Algebraic Functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Good evening,

In *Riemann surfaces* by Otto Forster there is the following theorem : Let $X$ be a Riemann surface and $P(T)=T^n+c_1T^{n_1}+\ldots + c_n\in\mathcal{M}(X)[T]$ an irreducible polynomial of degree $n,$ where $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is the set of all meromorphic functions on $X.$ Then there exist a Riemann surface $Y,$ a branched holomorphic n-sheeted covering $\pi : Y\to X$ and a meromorphic function $F$ on $Y$ such that $(\pi^{\ast}P)(F) = 0$.

We call $Y$ the algebraic function defined by the polynomial $P(T).$ (I don't restate the uniqueness of this Riemann surface).

**My question :** If $X$ is a compact Riemann surface, can we consider it as an algebraic function defined by some irreducible polynomial $P(T)\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{P}^1)[T]$?

I'm thinking of meromorphic functions on $X,$ which we can consider them as holomorphic mappings $X\to\mathbb{P}^1,$ having the smallest positive degree,i.e the inverse image of each point of $\mathbb{P}^1$ contains the smallest number of points. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes. That's the Riemann existence theorem, every compact Riemann surface is an algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Just to quibble, maybe it's best to talk about compact _connected_ Riemann surfaces, to avoid silly falsities about details.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I will search for this theorem.

Comment: @ paul garret : Yes, i'm sorry. In Otto Forster's book, he has a convention that every Riemann surface is connected.

Comment: BTW, the Riemann existence is in Forster (Cor. 14.13 in my edition).

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading this book and I try to do some exercises to be sure that I understand the theory. This question comes from the exercises of chapter 8, so that I didn't know the Riemann existence. Now i will continue my reading and will ask questions later :D 
Thanks for all your helps.